# IN() Function not returning results using percentage sign

Tags: php, mysql, sql

It's short and simple.

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL_NAME IN('%VALUE1%', '%VALUE2%')
```

However it doesn't seem to work, I've used LIKE for both values combined using `OR` and it returns results, so I'm certain that there's rows in the table with these values.. am I missing something here?

Does MYSQL `IN()` function accept percentage sign? What is the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: No, `IN` does not have `LIKE` functionality.

Comment: @jarlh how can I achieve that then?

Comment: `WHERE COL_NAME LIKE '%VALUE1%' OR COL_NAME LIKE '%VALUE2%'`

Comment: "*I've used LIKE for both values combined using OR and it returns results*" - It seems you already did it

Comment: @OfirWinegarten Alright, thanks.

Comment: @jarlh I've achieved that already, I was looking for an easier way, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try with [`RLIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL_NAME RLIKE 'VALUE[12]'
```

Keep in mind these sorts of queries tend to perform very badly because they require a full table scan. If you're doing this a lot you may want to adjust your schema to better represent your usage patterns.

Comment: I suppose OP just means two different _values_, not exactly value1 and value2.

Comment: @jarlh You can always adjust the regular expression accordingly. `VALUE1|VALUE2` seemed clunky.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL_NAME LIKE '%VALUE1%' OR COL_NAME LIKE '%VALUE2%'
```

Comment: jarlh had already mentioned this solution in comments 7 minutes before you. You should've asked him before adding it as an answer, or should've at least referenced his comment.

Comment: Actually the two solutions are different (one uses RLIKE and the other uses OR'ed LIKEs)

Comment: I was not talking about the other solution by **tadman**, I was talking about the comment under the answer by **jarlh**.